# numpy.unique: ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Tags: python, gdal, numpy

I'm trying to get the unique values of an array but am getting an error that doesn't make any sense.

Here is my pseudo code:

```
import numpy as np
import gdal

# I have a .tif file, call it inputRaster:

ds = gdal.Open(inputRaster)    
dt = ds.GetRasterBand(1).DataType
ncols = ds.RasterXSize
nrows = ds.RasterYSize
outArr = ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()

print dt # prints 2 (uint16)
print ncols # prints 55500
print nrows # prints 55500

print outArr.shape # prints (55500, 55500)
print outArr.dtype # prints uint16
```

but:

```
print np.unique(outArr)
```

gives me the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 197, in unique
 flag = np.concatenate(([True], ar[1:] != ar[:-1]))
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

My only input is the one array that I want to get unique values for. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error message which was caused by me handing over a numpy matrix (not an array) to np.unique.
You can make sure that a (multi-dimensional) array is passed by writing

```
print np.unique(np.array(outArr))
```

Comment: That's really strange because I deal with multi-dimensional numpy matrices all the time (often using np.unique to print the unique elements) and have never run into this problem. But thank you for the suggestion, I'll remember this next time I get the error. Thanks!